# Вызов диалога выбора приложения для открытия файла определенного типа

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

В ES проводнике реализована возможность открытие файла при помощи нескольких возможных программ на выбор. Как сделать что-нибудь подобное? Реализовано ли это стандартными библиотеками или нужно искать самописный компонент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не силен в ES проводнике, потому предположу, что там есть 2 возможных сценария:

1. Не назначена приложение по умолчанию для данного типа `Intent`'а в этом случае ось сама выкатит список приложений, которые могут обработать
2. Даже если назначено приложение по умолчанию, то ES проводник все равно предлагает юзеру выбор.

В первом случае - ничего делать не надо, ну или пойти в настройки и потереть умолчания.

Во втором случае надо самому городить огород:

Сначала получаем список приложений, которые могут обработать наш `intent`

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Далее по списку [ResolveInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) - строим диалог выбора - благо все данные `ResolveInfo` содержит: иконка, название и проч.

После того как юзер выбрал нужный `resolveInfo` - запускаем его примерно так:

```
ActivityInfo activity=resolveInfo.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activity.name);
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
intent.setComponent(name);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Тут немного есть)

```
public class FilePiker extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText textFile;
private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_piker);
    Button buttonPick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    textFile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    buttonPick.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");//тут тип файлов(все)
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

        }});
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();//возвращает путь файла
                textFile.setText(FilePath);
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Тут открывается диалог для выбора файла, а мне нужно открыть свой файл, например, docx на выбор при помощи приложений, которые могут это сделать (Polaris Office, ThinkFree Office и прочие установленные в системе)

Comment: Можно попробовать выбранный файл выполнить